# How can I get java.util.InputMismatchException error after getting values from Scanner in Java?

Tags: java

I have a problem about showing `java.util.InputMismatchException` error from Scanner.
I created two integer values as `int value1` and `int value2` in InputObject.
Next, I read **12.5** and **0** values from scanner and I got `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero` error.

How can I get `java.util.InputMismatchException` error ?

Here is my code snippet which is shown below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        InputObject inputObject = null;
        Scanner scanner = null;
        
        try {
            
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);
            
            int input1 = scanner.nextInt();

            int input2 = scanner.nextInt();
            
            inputObject = new InputObject(input1,input2);
            
            int result = inputObject.getValue1() / inputObject.getValue2();
            
            System.out.println(result);
            
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException error)
        {
            System.out.println(error);
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException error)
        {
            System.out.println(error);
        }
        finally {
            scanner.close();
            System.out.println("Program End");
        }
        
    }
```

The output like this

```
12.564
0
java.util.InputMismatchException
```

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation about Scanner (https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/ndale/Scanner.html)

> Returns the next token as an int. If the next token is not an integer, InputMismatchException is thrown.

Your code is right, but the try-catch blocks in Java work by throwing the first exception that occurs. This means you first receive dividing by zero, and then InputMismatch, try to change the order of catch blocks like so:

```
 catch (InputMismatchException error)
 {
    System.out.println(error);
 }
 catch (ArithmeticException error)
 {
    System.out.println(error);
 }
```

Comment: And `nextInt` is called before division, so it should throw an `InputMismatchException` before there is anything to divide. This advice would make sense if `InputMismatchException` extended `ArithmeticException`, but it doesn't.

Comment: @deyanm I changed the order but I still got java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero error instead of InputMismatchException after I read 13.678 and 0 in order.

Comment: @deyanm How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> [Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html)

So you should enter something which doesn't look like an `int` or is too big for `int`: `aaaa` or `3000000000`. Note that "doesn't look like an `int`" depends on the locale, as seen [under "Localized numbers" in the Scanner JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html).

> The output like this
>
> ```
> 12.564
> 0
> java.util.InputMismatchException
> ```

You'll get this with

```
scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);

int input1 = scanner.nextInt();
int input2 = scanner.nextInt();
```

Comment: I entered 12.5 and It's a float number. I need to enter this kind of values like 12.567 and 45.1298

Comment: I tested at JDoodle and get the expected result: https://jdoodle.com/ia/f2A. Are you maybe using a locale where `.` is a thousands separator?

Comment: If you need to enter floats, you need `nextFloat` (or `nextDouble`, or `nextBigDecimal`), not `nextInt`.

Comment: As I mentioned before, InputObject has two integer values not floats.

Comment: Please try `System.out.println(scanner.locale());`. As I said above, I suspect you are using a locale where `.` is a part of integer numbers (e.g. German). But even there it should only happen with 13.678 and not 12.5.

Comment: I got tr_TR after run this print

Comment: In Turkish from my check it's like in German, so `13.678` is not a float, it's `13678` (you can check by adding `scanner.useLocale(new Locale("tr", "TR"));` to the code in my JDoodle link above). If you don't want that, set the locale either for the Scanner with `scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);` or everywhere with `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US)`.

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't work. I also updated my code snippets.

Comment: That's because you also changed the code to use `nextFloat()`, and `12.5` is a valid float in US locale. If you keep `nextInt()`, you'll get `InputMismatchException` with `12.5`. Or if you enter something that doesn't look like a float (e.g. `aaa`).

Comment: But from the question I understood you want to get `InputMismatchException` for `12.5`, and from your first comment here that you want to enter `12.5` successfully (and I said that _in that case_ you should use a method which reads decimal numbers such as `nextFloat`).

Comment: I edited my post to show how output will be. Can you look through it if you don't mind?

Comment: See the edit (but to reiterate, `12.5` and `12.564` work differently here, so if you meant `12.564` you should have stated it in the question or at least checked what actually happens with `12.5`).

Comment: Also if your application reads numbers anywhere the same applies; you probably don't want `.` for decimal separator in one place and `,` (normal for Turkish) in other places. So please consider reading about locales in Java in general.

Comment: When I read `12,564` and then `0` , I get `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`. When I read `12,564` then I get  `InputMismatchException`. The program shows this output when I read `12.564` and then `0` and I get `InputMismatchException`

Comment: "The program shows this output when I read 12.564 and then 0 and I get InputMismatchException" Yes, that's what you specifically asked for in your question. `12,564` wasn't mentioned before, but it's an integer in US locale so you are doing `12564/0`. If you want it to fail with `InputMismatchException` as well, pick a locale where neither `,` nor `.` are the grouping separator. https://www.localeplanet.com/java/index.html has a list.

Comment: Is it possible to share all codes. I still get `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero error` although I can define a locale as US in scanner.

Comment: "I still get java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero error" With `12,564` or `12.564`? For `12,564` that's the expected result in the US locale, as the previous comment says. The full code is in https://jdoodle.com/ia/f4c.